# JMeter command line - linux version vs windows version

Tags: windows, linux, apache, jmeter

I'm been using JMeter on a linux box, under the command line for a little bit. works fine.

Today, I tried it on a windows box (new client, etc) and it does work but the OUTPUT is waay different, in the console window.

The linux version dumps to the console a running commentary of what is going on -> Min/Max/Throughput/Error messages, etc. etc.

On windows, there's non of that.. eg..

```
C:\Users\Administrator>c:\temp\jakarta-jmeter-2.3.4\bin\jmeter -n -t "C:\Users\A
dministrator\Desktop\JMeter Test Files\MyProject.jmx" -Dthrea
ds=10 -Dloop=10 -Drampup=1
Created the tree successfully using C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\JMeter Test Files\MyProjectjmx
Starting the test @ Fri Oct 23 21:08:37 PDT 2009 (1256357317843)
Waiting for possible shutdown message on port 4445
Tidying up ...    @ Fri Oct 23 21:09:09 PDT 2009 (1256357349008)
... end of run
```

Is there a setting i need to set? something i'm missing from the configuration file?

*Note: Please don't tell me to stick with the Linux version - lets keep any religious wars out of this discussion.*

Comment: Did you have any success with this? I'm running into the same problem - well close, it gets to "Waiting for posible shutdown message" and then just sits there for far longer than the test usually takes via the gui.

Comment: >jmeter -n -t Sequential_UAT_DynamicDataComparisonScript.jmx

Comment: nope. i ended up using the gui client on both windows and linux .. and ended with using the windows version.

Answer (score 1):

Basically when you are running your script from windows, you are not mentioning where your output should store. Check if you are using any listeners and storing the results somewhere on the windows box. 
You can add one more parameter as - -l  in the command line to get the help